# HTML elements not positioning correctly across screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I made a basic HTMl page with a sidebar and a content area. My problem is my content area is not not positioning correctly across screen sizes. Specifically, the distance between my sidebar and page content is smaller on a small screen than a larger screen. This is despite the fact that my sidebar's width is `150px` and i set the `margin-left` attribute for my `page_content` to be also `150px`.

Here is a screenshot of the smaller screen:

[image: Small Screen]

Here is a screenshot of the larger screen:

[image: Larger screen]

Here is a link to the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ds9jpj4/

How can I edit my css so the spacing is consistent between smaller & larger screens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you just have smaller pixels, so 150px becomes a small number of millimeters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap `container` class. Try using `container-fluid` instead.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Pixel, I think you should go by percentage of screen like 25%, 75%, that will look identical in ratio across all media size.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to this (bootstrap) CSS rule which becomes active above 768px:

```
.container {
    max-width: 750px;
}
```

just use a different class name, an additional class that overwrites this setting, or an additional rule that overwrites it.